flet: Geolocator Control must be added to the page first
Делаю определение геолокации с картой во flet. Когда хочу получить текущие координаты выходит ошибка:
AssertionError: Geolocator Control must be added to the page first
Хотя в коде есть page.overlay.append(gl). Если я делаю page.add(gl), то выходит просто пустой экран, и карта не показывается. Если убрать определение геолокации то на экране появляется карта и все работает (кроме геолокации)
Код:
import random
import flet as ft
import flet.map as map


def main(page: ft.Page):
    gl = ft.Geolocator(
        location_settings=ft.GeolocatorSettings(
            accuracy=ft.GeolocatorPositionAccuracy.LOW
        ),
    )
    page.overlay.append(gl)
    pos = gl.get_current_position()

    page.add(
        map.Map(
            expand=True,
            configuration=map.MapConfiguration(
                initial_center=map.MapLatitudeLongitude(pos.latitude, pos.longitude),
                initial_zoom=40,
                interaction_configuration=map.MapInteractionConfiguration(
                    flags=map.MapInteractiveFlag.ALL
                ),
            ),
            layers=[
                map.TileLayer(
                    url_template="https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
                    on_image_error=lambda e: print("TileLayer Error"),
                )
            ],
        ),
    )

ft.app(target=main)

